# Yeoman, grunt and bower: is possible to install bootstrap without javascript file?

Tags: gruntjs, bower, bower-install, grunt-wiredep

I install bootstrap using `bower install bootstrap`

I'm using grunt to build my project. I'm trying to add bootstrap and exclude bootstrap.js file.

```
// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
wiredep: {
  options: {
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
  },
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    exclude: ['bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
  }
}
```

Hower `bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js` is always included.

How can I exclude bootstrap javascript file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that `exclude: ['bootstrap.js']` solves my problem. However this is not very clear documented...